# approximation to scaling transformation in fin. maths application?

Tags: approximation, finance

I wonder if someone could help with an approximation to an "invert and scale" transformation
that occurs in a (simple) financial maths problem.  It has aspects that looks as through
they may be familiar from other applications (renormalization methods in physics?) and
I suspect may part of a more general theory.

The function in question is this

$$ C(y,z)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\textrm{erf}\left(\frac{z+y^{2}/2}{\sqrt{2}y}\right) 
-\frac{e^{-z}}{2}-\frac{e^{-z}}{2}\textrm{erf}\left(\frac{z-y^{2}/2}{\sqrt{2}y}\right) $$

The range of $C(y;z)$ is  $[(1-e^{-z}):\infty]$.  [Observant readers will see $C$ as the price of a (scaled) call option as a function of $y$, the variance and $z$, the moneyness. The lower limit of the range is the intrinsic value.]
Let $C^{-1}$ be the inverse of $C$ with respect to $y$ i.e.  $C^{-1}(C(y;z))=y$.

What I am looking at is the quantity
$$ V_{sp}(V; z, k)= C[k C^{-1}(V);z] $$
where $k$ is a parameter.

The derivatives of $C$ is easy to obtain: $\frac{\partial C}{\partial y}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z/2} e^{-(z^{2}+y^{4}/4)/(2y^{2})}$ and $\frac{\partial^{2} C}{\partial y^{2}}= -\frac{1}{4}y\left( 1-\frac{4z^{2}}{y^{4}} \right) \frac{\partial C}{\partial y} $, so there is an inflection at  $y=\sqrt{2 |z|}$, $C$ is convex below this point and concave above.

Intuitively I expect a power law kind of behaviour $V_{sp}(V) \simeq V^{f(k,z)}$. For $|z| \gg 0$ (further out of the money options) I would imagine the exponent is bigger, however I struggle to show this.

For lower values of $y$ a plot of $C(y)$, one could argue for an approximate exponential form

small $y$:   $C(y)\simeq e^{y}$ and hence $V_{sp}(V)=V^{k}$

For larger values of $y$ one could argue for an log form

large $y$:   $C(y)\simeq \ln y$ and hence $V_{sp}(V)=V + \ln k$

For arbitrary sizes of $k$, which can project variables from one region to another, I feel there might be some blend of this dependency. Does anyone recognize this kind of problem from other applications or elsewhere?

Comment: While not exactly, this reminds me of the context of volatility smile modelling

Comment: It is indeed very similar!  
The motivation here is a problem about hedging a complex contract with simple vanilla options.  If the contents of the hedge portfolio go up by factor of, say,  $x$,  is there a good heuristic for the scaling of the gains of the complex portfolio?
The smile valuation is about hedging different moneyness products with each other, but as you say, has some similar characteristics.

Comment: You might then be interested in the topic of static replication, which is an active area of research. It is also connected with smile modelling.